# gradle error cannot get the gradlepropertymodel V2 failed

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

in android studio , i created the project , after that the gradle error message is continues showing that "A build operation failed.     Cannot get GradlePropertiesModel (V2) for project 'GradleProject{path=':app'}' Cannot get GradlePropertiesModel (V2) for project 'GradleProject{path=':app'}' and please guide me to solve this problem . i've frustated to solve this for last 3 days

i want to solve this

Comment: deleting .idea folder and .gradle folder will restarting the IDE will solve this issue.